# Using regex backreference after matching n times

Tags: regex, atom-editor, regex-group

I need to match several strings in a puppet definition:

```
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1':  value => '4096' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2':  value => '8192' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3':  value => '16384' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6':     value => '0' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6': value => '0' }
```

And then using backreference add the same lines plus one more to end like this:

```
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1':  value => '4096' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2':  value => '8192' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3':  value => '16384' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6':     value => '0' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6': value => '0' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
```

I've tried this match pattern `(  sysctl::conf \{.*\}\n{1,})` and then replace it with `\1\n  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }`

The problem is that the backreference is referencing each line instead of all the grouped block to add my new line at the end. This is what I'm getting instead of the desired result:

```
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1':  value => '4096' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2':  value => '8192' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3':  value => '16384' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6':     value => '0' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6': value => '0' }
  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
```

Should I try to match the whole block of lines as one pattern instead of a multiple match of the same pattern?

I'm doing like this because I'm using Atom to search and replace all `sysctl::conf` entries in several files, that are not the same, and add the new entry after already existing ones.

Thank you :)

PS: Already know that in atom backreferences are called $1 instead of \1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this pattern

```
(?:\s*sysctl::conf \{.*\})+
```

After that replace with

```
\0\n  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }
```

Note the `\0`, since there wasn't any capturing group.

Explanation:

- `?:` is a Non-capturing group to capture the hole block (i.e. `\0`).
- `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ]).
- `+` at the end to capture all the matches.

Comment: It didn't work for me neither in vim nor in Atom.

It does match the whole block, but the backreference is only substituting the last line of it :(

Comment: You're right. With Vim you should write: `:%s/\%(\s*sysctl::conf {.*}\n\)\+/\0  sysctl::conf { 'net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing': value       => '1' }/g`. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Great! that worked fine! Thank you very much, Miguel :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)